# AngularJS: Value placeholder doesn't get replaced by actual value in scope object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am looping over a list of users and constructing a form for each user:

```
<form name="userForm">
  <input type="text" name="username_{{user.username}}">
  ...
</form>
```

I HTML, name="username_{{user.username}}" gets properly replaced by an actual username, e.g. name="username_Scholle", but in the scope object containing an object of this form, the name of the key doesn't have the name with replaced username, so it looks like this:

```
{
 ...   
 $userForm: {
   ...
   username_{{user.username}} : Constuctor
   ...
 } 
 ...
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: why exactly do you want to "solve" that?

Comment: @karaxuna: to access the value, set validity, etc. of the input field using the scope object

Comment: I've run into similar problem, but in this case you can use simpler approach, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind it to model:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="username">
```

get value in controller:

```
$scope.username;
```